# Laravel - Pass data view to view without saving to a database

Tags: database, laravel, view

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var supplier = $('select[name="supplier"]').val();
 var reqdate = $('input[name="reqdate"]').val();
 var priority = $('input[name="priority"]:checked').val();    
 if( supplier !='' && reqdate !='') {
        var supplier;
        var reqdate;
        var priority;
        var Material_ID = [];
        var Material_Name = [];
        var Mat_Quantity =[];
        var Unit_Price =[];
        var Cost =[];

        $('.matid').each(function(){
            Material_ID.push($(this).text());
        });

        $('.matname').each(function(){
            Material_Name.push($(this).text());
        }); 

        $('.unitprice').each(function(){
            Unit_Price.push($(this).text());
        });

        $('.matqty').each(function(){
            Mat_Quantity.push($(this).text());
        });

        $('.matcost').each(function(){
            Cost.push($(this).text());
        });

        var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    }
```

I want to send these data into a confirm page (another view)  without saving to a database. how can I do it? can I use sessions? above data obtained by a table and about to submit using Jquery.

this is the form

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'purchase.sessionstore','class'=>'form-horizontal','name'=>'materialdata']) !!}
```

controller function

```
public function storeSessionData(Request $request){

    if($request){


    }
}
```

I don't know how to put all of these data into a session and how to get them back in a view. please explain thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Use `session()` to work with them.

```
session(['your_data' => $your_data]); // save data so session
$my_data = session('your_data'); // get data from session
```

Answer (score 0):

use laravel official Session class

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
$value = Session::get('key');
```